# React: Variable inside Timer function does not update when passing props data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, timer, use-state

Im making a recording for a project. I have a timer function that is working correctly.
I have live performance data from a server that im passing into the timer function.
Im console.logging the data and it also works fine.
So I want a numberCount to be increased and displayed on my react app whenever this performance data is over 70.
However for some reason this if statement with props.data is not working properly.
If props.data is over 70 when timer starts it increments as the seconds in the timer. And if its below 70 when the timer starts it does not increment at all. So even though the data is over 70 my code does not react to this after I started the timer. So its like the timer function only reads the props.data variable when I start the timer. And not live as I want it. Im a beginner at react. My question is why isnt numberCount increasing when props.performanceData is over 70 live on my app?

```
function Timer(props) {

const [time, setTime] = useState({ ms: 0, s: 0, m: 0, h: 0 });
const [interv, setInterv] = useState();
const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);
const [numberCount, setNumberCount] = useState(0);


const start = () => {
    run();
    setStatus(1);
    setInterv(setInterval(run, 10));
};



var updatedMs = time.ms, updatedS = time.s, updatedM = time.m, updatedH = time.h;


const run = () => {
    if (updatedM === 60) {
        updatedH++;
        updatedM = 0;
    }
    if (updatedS === 60) {
        updatedM++;
        updatedS = 0;
    }
    if (updatedMs === 100){
        updatedS++;
        updatedMs = 0;
        if (props.performanceData >= 70){
            setNumberCount((currentNumber)=> currentNumber + 1);
        }
      
    }
  
   
    updatedMs++;
    return setTime({ ms: updatedMs, s: updatedS, m: updatedM, h: updatedH });

const stop = () => {
    clearInterval(interv);
    setStatus(2);
};

const reset = () => {
    clearInterval(interv);
    setStatus(0);
    setTime({ ms: 0, s: 0, m: 0, h: 0 });
};

const resume = () => start();

  return (
    <div>
        <div >{numberCount}</div>
        <div>{props.performanceData}</div>
            <div className='stopwatch'>

                <BtnComponent status={status} resume={resume} reset={reset} stop={stop} start={start} />

                <DisplayComponent  time={time} />

            </div>
    </div>
    )
}

function DisplayComponent(props) {
    const h = () => {
        if (props.time.h === 0) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return <span>{(props.time.h >= 10) ? props.time.h : "0" + props.time.h}</span>;
        }

}
//   :
return (
    <div>
       {h()} &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span>{(props.time.m >= 10) ? props.time.m: "0" + props.time.m}</span>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
        <span>{(props.time.s >= 10) ? props.time.s : "0" + props.time.s}</span>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
        <span>{(props.time.ms >= 10) ? props.time.ms : "0" + props.time.ms}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>


   );
}

export default DisplayComponent;

function BtnComponent(props) {

return (
    <div>
        {(props.status === 0) ?
        <button className='btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' onClick={props.start}>Start Record</button> : ""
      }
        {(props.status === 1)?
       <div>
         <button className='btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block' onClick={props.stop}>Pause Record</button> 
         <button className='btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block' onClick={props.reset}>Stop Record</button> 

        </div> : ""
    }
       {(props.status === 2)?
       <div>
         <button className='btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' onClick={props.resume}>Resume Record</button> 
         <button className='btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block' onClick={props.reset}>Stop Record</button> 

        </div> : ""
    }
    
    </div>
);
}

export default BtnComponent;
```

Comment: Where do you call `start`, `stop` and other functions?

Comment: I thought that wasnt relevant so I didnt include that, cuase I thought the problem was in the run function. I now added the other two components in the bottom of the code

Answer (score 0):

This is called a *stale state*. You may read about it here:

[Why am I seeing stale props or state inside my function?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)

To fix the problem you can use `useRef`:

```
const perf = useRef();
perf.current = props.performanceData;
```

```
if (perf.current >= 70) {
  setNumberCount((currentNumber) => currentNumber + 1);
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-lake-znh3ut?file=/src/App.js)

I'm also recommend reading [this documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/referencing-values-with-refs). It is really well written.

Comment: Now it works as it should! Thank you very much for your answer.